# Mysql and if/else statement in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

i have this SQL select query

```
SELECT * 
FROM bots 
WHERE id NOT IN (select botid 
                 from messages 
                 where messages.recipient = :recipient) 
limit 1
```

and i need to do something like that:

```
SELECT * 
FROM bots 
[if isset(recipient = $recipient AND sender = $sender)] 
  WHERE id IN (select botid 
               from messages 
               where messages.recipient = :recipient and sender = :sender) 
else 
  WHERE id NOT IN (select botid 
                   from messages 
                   where messages.recipient = :recipient) 
limit 1
```

[] - pseudo code

How make this query?

Bots table:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
| id       |  auth_token   |  messages_today  | vkid  |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 1       |  token   |                    0   | 2323  |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 2       |  token   |                     0  | 2343  |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Messages table:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
| id       |  recipient   |  sender  | botid  | messageid |
-----------------------------------------------------------
| 1        |  12          |        1  |     1  |      3322 |
-----------------------------------------------------------
| 2        |  12          |        2  |     2  |    332123 |
-----------------------------------------------------------
| 3        |  13          |        1  |     1  |    332123 |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: From your pseudocode, it is not clear how you want to apply that condition. It is generally possible to work conditions like that (based on presence/absence of input values) into the `WHERE` clause directly, with careful `()` grouping and `AND/OR` logic.

Comment: you want all bots in (List A) and if they are not in list A, then make sure they are not in (List B)?

Comment: @xQbert I want to get all bots which havent sent anything to this recipient if our sender != sender, for this i have bots and messages tables

Comment: Table structure sample data and expected results using sample data would be helpful.  I'll post a best guess as to what your after as an answer in a minute or two.

Comment: Ok so, in plain english...: if recipient and sender are provided to the query return all bots who received the message.
if r and s are not set, provided all bots who haven't received the message...  right?

Answer (score 1):

Using an outer join this will

- Return all bots from bots table
- and data from the message talbe that matches
- but then we eliminate the matching data returning only bots
  where a message having the recipient and sender provided do not exist for that particular bot

return all bots

```
Select * from bots B
LEFT JOIN messages M
  on M.BotID = B.ID
 and M.Sender = $sender
 and M.Recipient = $Recipient
Where M.BotID is null
```

Comment: This works but not correctly, if isset(sender = sender and recipient = recipient) we selecting botid from this row, only if not isset we are selecting where id not in (recipient = recipient)

Comment: Ok so, in plain English...: if recipient (r) and sender (s) are provided to the query return all bots who received the message. if r and s are not set, provided all bots who haven't received the message... right?